# classification using simple relationships between time series data

Tags: time-series, statistics, categorical-data

I am looking to predict which courses are taught by which university professors at my school. More specifically, for each semester and professor I want to know the probability breakdown of which classes that they are likely to teach.

I have a small dataset and a limited amount of features, but the patterns are fairly predictable:

- Most courses consist of an overlap of simple patterns where the professors for a class changes in a cyclic fashion. E.g. for a class, the cycle of professors may be `(A,B) -> (B,C) -> (C,A) -> ...`.
- Professors also typically have a simple cycle, e.g. `a -> b -> a -> c -> a -> b` for the courses `{a,b,c}` they teach. Another example might be that some professors only teach in the fall, etc.

The features are very basic, only:

- year
- semester (fall or spring)

I am looking at 'brute forcing' it with CATBoost - as I am not sure which direction to go in here.

If for the past two years, a professor has taught course X every semester, I would like my model to predict that instead of if they taught a different class for 10 years before teaching course X.

Which ML Model would be the best way to predict this information - and prefer more recent results?